# How to deploy nextjs app in AWS EC2 Ubuntu server? What is the config file?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, next.js, amazon-ec2, deployment

How can I run a Next.js project without using 'npm run start' or 'npm run dev'?
My aim to access it through the build.

This was my config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root /path/to/your/nextjs/app/.next/build;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I attempted multiple techniques from various blogs, but none proved successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too broad and vague, because normally Next.js requires Node.js server to run it.
But, it can be configured, and your project can be coded in such a way, to allow for a static HTML export of your Next.js app. You can find more details in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports).

If static HTML export is what you have, then after you've run `next build`, which generates an optimized version of your application for production in a specific folder structure, you can use a configuration similar to your example to serve the static files from this output folder. Or, you could copy those files and folder to another location of your liking and configure Nginx to serve from there.

Otherwise, you have to serve your Next.js app with a Node.js server and then point Nginx to do a reverse proxy to the port on which your server is listening on.
There is, of course, another option which is to run it in a Docker container.

As I've said in the beginning, it is a bit more complex than your question asserts. Maybe start with the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying), and go from there to get more knowledge, or be more specific and detailed, so that somebody can try to give more tailored-to-your-problem answers.